# How can i set wildcard subdomain for a domain bought from godaddy and DNS hosted in rout53

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

How can i set wildcard subdomain for a domain bought from godaddy and DNS hosted in rout53.

couldn't find a good guide on this.

however here is what I've done so far.

- bought the domain from go daddy.
- allocated an elastic ip in amazon and assigned it to my ec2 instance.
- in rout53 created a new host zone -> took the 4 ns and entered them as custom NS in godaddy.
- in rout53 -> record set I've added the following

sorry Table doesnt look very nice  -

```
Name               | Type  |    Value     | TTL |
www.example.com.   |   A   | 54.84.32.111 | 300 |
ftp.example.com.   | CNAME | example.com  | 300 |
*.example.com.     | CNAME | example.com  | 300 |
```

Do i need to change anything or the above will work as wildcard for example.com.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create NS records on your domain registrar for example.com which in your case is GoDaddy.  These NS records are the Name Servers that are assigned to your subdomain when you create it on Route 53. They look like something like this:

```
ns-1111.awsdns-36.co.uk.
ns-11.awsdns-10.com.
ns-111.awsdns-25.net.
ns-111.awsdns-60.org.
```

Then on your subdomain if you want to create a start record (*) that would be the root destination for your subdomain you can just create an 'A' or 'CNAME' pointer with no name.

After that all your requests to mysubdomain.example.com will get forwarded to Route 53.

Here's a sample picture of how to do it on GoDaddy:

[image: GoDaddy Example]

Comment: How can i create SN records on godaddy ? they wont let you create , they'll just let you assign NS to a domain. like i can take the NS i got from rout 53 and assign them to the domain in godaddy

Comment: rico thanks for the help so far. so the NS i got from rout53 when i create the host zone, should still be assigned to the example.com, and then also to create ns inside godaddy(like your image) and point it to one of the subdomains i got from rout 53 ?

Comment: 1. so the NS i got from rout53 when i create the host zone, should still be assigned to the example.com: No

Comment: 2. create ns inside godaddy(like your image) and point it to one of the subdomains i got from rout 53 ? : Yes

Comment: And the main domain will still point to that host even though we take the ns out ? should i create 4 ns for the subdomain ?

Comment: you don't need to create NS for the subdomain unless you want a subdomain.subdomain.example.com.  Yeah the main domain will still work as long as you didn't change the 'root' NS records that GoDaddy is using.

Comment: What happened with this ? Did you get it figured out ?

Comment: did not figure out how to do it your way. what i did is simply in the domain's zone info i've added an a record to the same ip with *